# AttributeError: object has no attribute print

Tags: python

In Microsoft Visual Studio, I am getting the error "Artist object has no attribute "object". What am I doing wrong? Here is my python code:

```
class Artist:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.albums = []

    def add_album(self, album):
        self.albums.append(album)

    def printLists(self):
        print('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))
        for alb in self.name:
            alb.printFunct('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))

class Album:
    #define what is in the album
    def __init__(self, albumTitle, artist):
        self.songs = []
        self.albumTitle = albumTitle
        artist.add_album(self)
        self.cls = albumTitle     

        artist.add_album(self)

    def addSongs(self, songTitle):
        self.songs.append(songTitle)

    def printFunct(self):
            for song in self.songs:
                print('{}({})'.format(song.nameSong, self.albumTitle))

class Song:

    def __init__(self, title, album):
        self.title = title        
        self.album = album

        album.addSongs(self)

class Playlist:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.songs = []

    def addSongs(self, song):
        self.songs.append(song)

    def printSongs(self):
        print(self.name)
        for song in self.songs:
            print('{}'.format(song.title))

hueyLewis = Artist( "Huey Lewis and the News" )
hallAndOats = Artist( "Hall and Oates" )
toto = Artist( "Toto" )
bigBamBoom = Album( "Big Bam Boom", hallAndOats )
sports = Album( "Sports", hueyLewis )
theSeventhOne = Album( "The Seventh One", toto )
four = Album( "IV", toto )

s1 = Song( "If This is it", sports )
s2 = Song( "Bad is Bad", sports )
s3 = Song( "Out of Touch", bigBamBoom )
s4 = Song( "Did it in a minute ", bigBamBoom )
s5 = Song( "Pamela", theSeventhOne )
s6 = Song( "Africa", four )


myAwesomePlaylist = Playlist( "My Awesome Playlist " )
myAwesomePlaylist.addSongs( s1 )
myAwesomePlaylist.addSongs( s2 )
myAwesomePlaylist.addSongs( s3 )
myAwesomePlaylist.addSongs( s4 )
myAwesomePlaylist.addSongs( s5 )
myAwesomePlaylist.addSongs( s6 )
hallAndOats.print('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))
hueyLewis.print('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))
toto.print('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))
myAwesomePlaylist.print()
```

The output is supposed to print out the artist and the song of the artist etc.

Comment: Add the full trace to your question (including line #).

Comment: Also, side-note: If this is Python 2, and you haven't done `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the module, `print` is a keyword, and you can't name methods or variables `print` at all. With the `__future__` import, or in Python 3 no matter what, `print` stops being a reserved keyword and the restriction goes away.

Comment: `Artist` instances does not have `print` method. What they have declated is `printLists` method. Same goes to other classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't define a print method for any of your classes. Therefore, the objects created by those classes won't have a print attribute. I believe this is what you wanted though:

```
hallAndOats.printLists()
hueyLewis.printLists()
toto.printLists()
myAwesomePlaylist.printSongs()
```

**EDIT**

You have two separate mistakes in `Artist.printLists()`. That method should look like this:

```
def printLists(self):
    print('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))
    for alb in self.albums:
        alb.printFunct()
```

You were iterating through the individual characters in the name of the artist instead of the albums that the artist produced. Also, you were calling `Album.printFunct()` incorrectly. As you defined it, it does not have any explicit parameters, yet you were calling it with `'Songs by {}'.format(self.name)` as an explicit argument.

**EDIT 2**

You have yet another error in your code, but this time in `Album.printFunct()`. That method should look like this:

```
def printFunct(self):
    for song in self.songs:
        print('{}({})'.format(song.title, self.albumTitle))
```

You were using `song.nameSong`, which appears nowhere else in your code (least of all as an instance variable of `Song`).

**EDIT 3**

You have another error in `Album.__init__`. You are adding every album to each artist twice. Remove one of the `artist.add_album(self)`s from the `Album` constructor to fix this.

Comment: Now I am getting str object has no attribute 'printLists' error. :(

Comment: @HawkBlade124 Again, what's the exact error and on which line is it happening? Just saying that it's causing some kind of error doesn't help me to help you.

Comment: @HawkBlade124 I just identified and fixed all of the errors in your code. Now everything is working properly. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I did everything correctly, and it successfully prints out a list. but it doesn't print out the songs according to each artist. like so


`Hall and Oates
Songs by Hall and Oates
Songs by Hall and Oates
Songs by Hall and Oates
Songs by Hall and Oates`

Comment: You're going to have to give me more information for me to help. Your code, with my modifications, was working fine for me this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Your error tells you something: Artist objects don't have the attribute `print`.  They have `printLists`.  Just change those last lines to use `printLists` instead of `print`.  The playlist, however, should be `printSongs`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is from here:

```
hallAndOats.print('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))
hueyLewis.print('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))
toto.print('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))
myAwesomePlaylist.print()
```

You should use

## .printLists for class 'Artist',

## .printFunct for class 'Album' and

## .printSongs for class 'Playlist'

You can only use the functions you have defined in you class. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that when I get home! :)

Comment: @HawkBlade124 No problem! Hope this will help you fix the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `printLists()` on the `Artist` object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd urge you to have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, you could have whittled your code all the way down to this and still had the same problem:

```
class Artist:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.albums = []
    def add_album(self, album):
        self.albums.append(album)
    def printLists(self):
        print('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))
        for alb in self.name:
            alb.printFunct('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))

hallAndOats = Artist( "Hall and Oates" )

hallAndOats.print('Songs by {}'.format(self.name))
```

From there, it should be pretty clear that the reason for the error is that you didn't define a method called `print` on `Artist` objects.

(Also, in the future, please provide the full traceback so that people can see exactly what and where the exception is.)